# RKResponseDescriptor method

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I'm doing a GET request with RESTKit and my RKResponseDescriptor is deprecated. I know this is because I don't have the method parameter in it, but I don't know what I would put for the method parameter. Here is my current code:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *nameResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:nameMapping                                                                                                  
    //I don't know what would go here under method
    method:(RKRequestMethod)method                                                                                   
    pathPattern:@"/projects/20090611/providers/find"                                                                                             
    keyPath:@"providers"                                                                                         
    statusCodes:statusCodeSet];
```

Answer (score 3):

Quite simply you set the parameter to `RKRequestMethodGET` because it is the response descriptor to be used when a GET request is made.